# Error establishing database connection error during first Wordpress run

Tags: database

I have followed the instructions from this site https://skillcrush.com/2015/04/14/install-wordpress-mac/ to install wordpress and MAMP on my MacBook. Everything worked out fine, but during the last step, the site is showing, Error establishing Database Connection. 
               I am confused as to what caused this problem. Could it be because during the first time I turned in the MAMP server, I denied Firewall Access, I am not exactly sure what that was, but I accidentally denied it. Could it be the reason that it is showing this error? All the other solutions I googled are usually caused after the installation. Please help.

Comment: Try reviewing the following codex for some guidance: http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Error_Establishing_Database_Connection

Comment: The firewall situation is the likely culprit. Configure the firewall application to allow MAMP to use the network.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by incorrect database credentials in your `wp-config.php` file. Open that file and verify that the database server, name, user, and password are correct.

Comment: the user and password are set to root, and the database name is correct

Comment: @Soumil, are you running WordPress on a MacBook and are you familiar with the command line tool? If so, can you log in to your mysql server via command line using the user and password settings of ```root``` as you stated you have above?